# Unix: "ls" command shows files with ? after the extension

Tags: java, shell, unix, ls, filewriter

I have written a shell script (test.sh) using Java. This shell script actually does a copy job from one file to the other. After the execution of the shell script I have opened the directory from *Console* and typed `ls`. It shows the output file with **?** after the extension.

example : foo.csv?

```
File execFile = new File(file);
    FileWriter fwFile;
    try {
        fwFile = new FileWriter(execFile);
        execFile.setExecutable(true);
        BufferedWriter bwFile = new BufferedWriter(fwFile);
        bwFile.write(strOutput.substring(0, 2));
        bwFile.write("\r\n");
        bwFile.write("cd " + strOutput);
        bwFile.write("\r\n");
        bwFile.write("mkdir " + strOutput);
        bwFile.write("\r\n");
        bwFile.write(strUnixPath);
        bwFile.write("\r\n");
        bwFile.write("cd " + strWorkingPath + IPlatinumConstants.FS+"lib"+IPlatinumConstants.FS+"Unx");
        bwFile.write("\r\n");
        bwFile.write("echo Cut Src Start time %time%");
        bwFile.write("\r\n");

                bwFile.write("cp " + " \"" + strSourceFilePath + "\"  \""
                        + strOutput + "copy_A\"");
                bwFile.write("\r\n");
```

My guess is that, while creating the shell script using java, something needs to taken care of

Comment: Some text editors may save backup and temporary files like that. What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Consider posting the code that generates and executes the shell script and an example of the generated shell script

Comment: The OP probably saved the file in Windows and now it has Windows file endings. Use an utility like dos2unix to convert the script.

Comment: you are almost right.. it has something to do with Windows file endings.. but i am trying to create the file in unix environment only

Comment: remove \r from \r\n and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bwFile.write("\r\n");
```

replace these lines with UNIX line endings

```
bwFile.write("\n");
```

or set the proper line separator

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
bwFile.newLine()
```